# Swift: Union Type in Property Wrapper

Tags: swift, union-types, property-wrapper

In Swift, you can specify a union type using an enum. For example:

```
enum IntOrString {
    case int(Int)
    case string(String)
}
```

Now I want to write a property wrapper, which I can apply to properties of a type from my union type. However, I don't want to expose the enum I use behind the scenes. Instead, a user of my property wrapper should be able to apply it to a `String` or `Int` property directly.

One approach would work as follows.

```
@propertyWrapper
struct Managed<T> {
    private var storage: IntOrString
    var wrappedValue: T {
        get {
            switch storage {
                case .int(let int):
                    return int as! T
                case .string(let string):
                    return string as! T
            }
        }
        set {
            if T.self == Int.self {
                storage = .int(newValue as! Int)
            } else if T.self == String.self {
                storage = .string(newValue as! String)
            } else {
                fatalError("Property has an illegal type")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately however, I lose static type safety with this approach, as a user can now apply `Managed` to a property which is neither `Int` nor `String` and would only get a runtime error, once he tries to set the property.

```
struct Foo {
    @Managed var bar: Double
}

let foo = Foo(bar: 0) // fatal error
```

As far as I'm aware, I cannot specify a type constraint on `T` which only allows for `T` to be `Int` or `String`.
So is there any way in Swift to get static type safety on union types in this scenario?
If not, are there more elegant workarounds to my approach?

Comment: You would need to make this non-generic, and define two separate initializers, `init(wrappedValue: Int)` and `init(wrappedValue: String)`. But this is rather suspicious, what problem are you trying to with `IntOrString`?

Comment: A "union type" as you call it isn't some well defined design pattern in swift but a solution often used when we need to decode json from a poorly designed rest api that might return different types for the same attribute. So why do you want to use an enum such this in the first place?

Comment: I wanted to implement a property wrapper which allows properties of certain types to be stored to disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I'm aware, I cannot specify a type constraint on `T` which only allows for `T` to be `Int` or `String`.

Actually you can with a helper protocol

```
protocol OnlyStringOrInt {}
extension Int: OnlyStringOrInt {}
extension String: OnlyStringOrInt {}
```

With this solution the property wrapper can be reduced to

```
@propertyWrapper
struct Managed<T: OnlyStringOrInt> {
    var wrappedValue: T
}
```

Then `bar` declared as `Double` raises this compiler error

> Generic struct 'Managed' requires that 'Double' conform to 'OnlyStringOrInt'

Comment: Thanks! I thought of that right after posting my question. The problem unfortunately isn't fully solved, since I still need to keep the dynamic error in place in case protocol conformance is used on other types. However, it does give me stronger guarantees.

Comment: Declare `OnlyStringOrInt` private.

Comment: But then I need to also declare `Managed` private...

Comment: Right. I take it back 